# Citing a page number in only one of many references

Tags: biblatex, citing

Using BibLatex, I'm trying to add a citation that refers to a particular page, but I'd also like to add other, normal citations.

Currently I have:

```
...given here for the ground state as~\cite[eq.~6.34]{Foot2005} or \cite{Woodgate1980}:
```

But I've had to manually split them. What I'm looking for is code that produces an output like

```
...state as [1 (eq. 6.34), 2]
```

or something similar.

Comment: `\cites[eq.~6.34]{Foot2005}{Woodgate1980}`

Comment: Fantastic, thought it would be easy. If you put this as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multi-cite version

```
\cites[eq.~6.34]{Foot2005}{Woodgate1980}
```

Using `\cites` you can specify the pre- and postnote for each citation separately. The syntax is

```
\cites(global pre)(global post)[first pre][first post]{first key}...[last pre][last post]{last key}
```

There are multi-cite versions of all standard citation commands, you can obtain them by adding an `s` to the end of the citation command, e.g. `\parencite` -> `\parencites`.